# count number of colored diamond in the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I have similar images such as the below image. each image has a different number of colored diamonds in the below of that. I need some image processing method which counts the number of colored diamonds with OpenCV and python.
[image]

for example, in the above picture, I have only two colored diamonds out of five.

Answer (score 1):

Trim the area with diamonds and calculate the average color. Compare with 6 values (0,1,2,3,4,5 diamond), which is closer. Enough to use PIL.

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling if you know where the diamonds are, and I will assume that this is a separate problem.
Just take pixels inside the diamonds and check if they are white (values (255, 255, 255) or close).

---

For location, turn the image to binary (black/non-black). Template matching will work wonderfully.

Comment: The main problem is locating the diamonds in the images. I have not any solid solution for finding them.

Comment: @user1924748: you should have said that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out template matching in Opencv. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Since you know what the diamonds look like, just you that as the template, then count how many times that template appears in the larger image.

Answer (score 0):

The diamond dimensions are same so you can use this property of them. Here are the step to apply:

- Load the image and convert to gray scale
- Apply [threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) function
- [Find and draw contours](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)
- Draw fitted rectangle for each contour ( [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40203932/drawing-a-rectangle-around-all-contours-in-opencv-python) )
- Filter all rectangle by using the dimensions(in pixel) of the each rectangle and get only the diamonds.
- Check inside of each rectangle color on source image and count them

***Note:*** In my opinion,template matching can cause some problems but you can try it too to see the results.